# How do you manage ssh keys with multiple contributors?

Tags: github, ssh

On linux, I have just setup an ssh connection to one of my private repos on github, i have always used https up until now, one thing i dont understand though is how another contributor can access the repo if he wanted to clone it? Do i need to add another public key to the repo from him generating another rsa_id? And what if i want to clone it on another computer, do i need to transfer the key files?

Answer (score 1):

You would normally use Github's mechanisms for access control. If you want to allow access to a private github repo, use the Collaborators tab under settings for the repo. You add people by Github user account and they manage their own SSH keys with github.

If you want to clone your own repo on a different machine then you'd need to add a new SSH key for that machine to your own account.